# Is "a seagull soaring just beside my ear" clear?

Tags: meaning

Is the meaning of this sentence clear:

> A seagull soaring just beside my ear distracted me from  the string of thoughts.

I meant that the seagull soared very near to the narrator.

Comment: "Soaring" to me implies that the seagull was flying very high up. Is this the case? If not, you might try "wooshing", "flying" or "zooming". You might also want to consider "train of thought" instead of "string of thoughts".

Comment: No, they are near the ground. Thank you for your corrections. I also wonder if "just beside my ear" makes sense in this sentence?

Comment: Maybe "past" my ear or head would be better.

Comment: Seagulls have an uncanny ability to stay in the same place relative to other objects, even when they are moving.  So, "soaring just *beside*" refers to that ability of theirs, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

I have several points.

I agree with JMB that "soaring" at least suggests substantial height.

Also, "beside" tends to suggest a place where something remains. If Bill says "Sarah walked beside me", I will assume that Bill was also walking, because if he was standing still, then Sarah would be walking *past* Bill, not *beside* him. So, unless there is a headwind so that the gull is soaring in place beside the speaker's ear, I would use a different preposition.

Finally, "the string of thoughts" sounds non-native to me. I think you want to use "my" instead of "the" there. It's true that "train of thought" sounds more natural, but some would view it as too much of a cliche. Others would disagree, arguing that it's just the expression we use for that.

Despite all that, the sentence was certainly understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the meaning is clear.
However, whether it flows depends on your audience:  In the US the sentence would sound odd,  We would say RIGHT beside my ear, whereas in other English speaking countries it is common to say JUST beside my ear.

On the issue of soaring, there is nothing strange or uncanny about a seagull's ability to stay in one place in the air -- it is simply a balance between the upward movement of a flow of air and the downward force of gravity == and the English word for that is SOARING.  So, while we often think of soaring as a high altitude thing, sometimes it is and sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

"Soar," From M-W:

> to fly or sail often at a great height by floating on air currents

In practical terms, this means that the bird isn't flapping its wings. So you should be sure that you mean to say the bird isn't flapping its wings and just smoothly gliding by on air currents alone. This normally occurs at great height, because that's where air currents really start to pick up, but it's not impossible at lower heights (although that's usually just referred to as "gliding" because the lack of air currents doesn't make it sustainable).

If you mean to say that the seagull quickly zoomed by the person's ear, "dove just past/just beside my ear" would be a pretty good option, I think. Diving gets across the point that the bird isn't flapping its wings and is going fast.